# Why does my page view show a 500 error in the browser?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I created a view to replace the user's page.

I want that when a user visits another user's account, he has a 403 error.

Here is its configuration :

[image]

[image]

When I go to the account of the current user, it works. But when I go to the account of another user, I have a 500 error in my browser :

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

In the Drupal logs, I have a lot of errors but no details :

[image]

In the Apache logs I have the following error :

```
[Sun Nov 18 13:02:17.467832 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17384:tid 140440486577920] [client 185.228.231.100:63896] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/display/PathPluginBase.php on line 397\n'
```

I do not understand why the page does not work. How can I fix this ?

- I increased the php memory to 256MB but there is the same error.
- If I delete the contextual filter, it works. But you need the context filter for my view.

Comment: After you increase the memory, did the error change? as the error you've posted here looks like it's still capped to using 128MB.

Comment: 403 is a client side error? Ah! I forgot my tea. Can I set this a simple message after click that "You do not have permission to access this" instead of 403 forbidden [as it works for user level permissions]